# PHPUnit test doesn't 'go' into if conditional

Tags: php, phpunit

```
public function test_cleansUpHouses()
{
    $houseWithNoHP = new \DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\House();
    $houseWithNoHP->setHitPoints(0);
    $houseWithNoHP->setCurrentAttackers(1);

    $houseWithHP = new \DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\House();
    $houseWithHP->setCurrentAttackers(1);

    $houseWithHPWasNotAttacked = new \DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\House();
    $houseWithHPWasNotAttacked->setCurrentAttackers(1);

    $houseCollection = new \DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\Collection(
        [$houseWithNoHP, $houseWithHP, $houseWithHPWasNotAttacked]
    );

    $this->mockHouseModel->expects($this->at(0))
        ->method('hasBeenAttacked')
        ->with($houseWithNoHP)
        ->willReturn(true);

    $this->mockHouseModel->expects($this->at(1))
        ->method('hasBeenAttacked')
        ->with($houseWithHP)
        ->willReturn(true);

    $this->mockHouseModel->expects($this->at(2))
        ->method('hasBeenAttacked')
        ->with($houseWithHPWasNotAttacked)
        ->willReturn(false);

    $this->mockHouseModel->expects($this->at(0))
        ->method('requiresDestroying')
        ->with($houseWithNoHP)
        ->willReturn(true);

    $this->mockHouseModel->expects($this->at(1))
        ->method('requiresDestroying')
        ->with($houseWithHP)
        ->willReturn(false);

    $expectedHouses = [$houseWithHP, $houseWithHPWasNotAttacked];

    $cleanedUpHouses = $this->createObject()->cleanUpHouses($houseCollection);
    $this->assertEquals($expectedHouses, $cleanedUpHouses->getHouses());
}

private function createObject()
{
    return new Collection($this->mockHouseModel);
}
```

And here's the model under test

```
public function cleanUpHouses(\DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\Collection $collection)
{
    foreach($collection->getHouses() as $key => $house) {
        if(!$this->houseModel->hasBeenAttacked($house)) {
            break;
        }

        if($this->houseModel->requiresDestroying($house)) {
            unset($collection->getHouses()[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

However, this line `if($this->houseModel->requiresDestroying($house)) {` is never being returned as `true`, even though I have the line

```
    $this->mockHouseModel->expects($this->at(0))
        ->method('requiresDestroying')
        ->with($houseWithNoHP)
        ->willReturn(true);
```

The error I'm getting.

```
1) DeadStreet\Model\House\Collection_Test::test_cleansUpHouses
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
     0 => DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\House Object (...)
     1 => DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\House Object (...)
+    2 => DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\House Object (...)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the code is working correctly?

This line

```
unset($collection->getHouses()[$key]);
```

uses a copy of your array to execute an unset on it.

Example:

```
class Test 
{
    private $array = array("a" => 1, "b" => 2);

    public function unsetArray()
    {
        unset($this->getArray["a"]);
    }

    public function getArray()
    {
        return $this->array;
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->unsetArray();
```

The method `unsetArray` always resets on a copy here, not the actual array. If you want something like that. You have to use the actual array like this.

```
public function unsetArray()
{
    unset($this->array["a"]);
}
```